# using an older version of scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I have `conda 4.5.11` installed in my machine and `Python 3.7.0` and I am trying to install `scikit-learn 0.19` using the following procedure:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==0.19
```

but I get the following errors:

> Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
>
> Command "/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/x5/t6zy26vd4gq36xgq6yl45p2h0000gn/T/pip-install-7h06grkn/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/x5/t6zy26vd4gq36xgq6yl45p2h0000gn/T/pip-record-eem8zdll/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x5/t6zy26vd4gq36xgq6yl45p2h0000gn/T/pip-install-7h06grkn/scikit-learn/

and a bunch of warnings too. How can I use an older version of sklearn with an anaconda installation of python?

Comment: `conda install scikit-learn==0.18.2`?

Comment: You say you want to install 0.19, then use the command for 0.18!! Also, I think that there will be some compatibility issues with python 3.7 and scikit 0.18. Can you describe the usecase as to why you want to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda install scikit-learn==0.19` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, needed `scikit-learn==0.18.1`. What worked for me was uninstalling the current Conda, going to https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ and finding the version that I needed.

For reference, the one that worked for me was: `Anaconda3-4.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe` from March 2017.

After that, restart the IDE, and all dependencies were on the version I needed.